# Azure AD B2C - user type 'Guest' or 'Member'

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Can someone explain the differences between userType `Guest` and `Member`? What are consequences when creating a user in B2C? Can't find it in the docs.

I create a user with Graph API and [here's the docs for User entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity). It has `userType` in there and it can be `Guest` or `Member`. But I'd like to understand this difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should always create your Azure AD B2C users with UserType=Member.**

UserType=Guest is a implementation detail of Azure AD B2B which is a feature of regular Azure AD and not supported in Azure AD B2C.

Comment: May I ask why it's possible then to create an Azure DB B2C user as `UserType=Guest` if one should never create a B2C user as `UserType=Guest`? Seems like this should not be possible? Is MS trying to shoehorn the legacy AD codebase into Azure AD B2C??

Comment: I created a new user through the azure portal in the AzureAD B2C Users area. That user has user type=Member shown in the portal Users list but the user cannot login through the Azure AD B2C user flow. Only the users created through the Azure AD B2C user flow are able to logins w/ the user flow. All these users are listed in the Azure AD B2C User list, all with the userType=Member but how can I can distinguish between users created w/ user flows vs users created through the azure portal (New user button in the portal)

Comment: To invite my sysadmins to manage the B2C users and userflows, I had to create them as guests so that they can use the same user and credentials than on our main Azure AD. Otherwise, it would create them a different account if I used a member. Therfore, I would tend to disagree with the provided answer.